# Matrix fields within matrix field

Tags: matrix

Is there a way to place matrix fields inside of matrix fields or also to setup a matrix field with existing fields?

We are currently trying not to have duplicate content in terms of fields, but that doesnt seem possible?

Comment: It is currently not possible to have matrix fields within matrix fields.

Comment: Yes nextflo, actually a good idea to do so. That's what I wanted to do with some non-matrix fields not long ago. But another problem with this approach was, that you have to have the same title connected to that field, in each entry type / section you are using it. Sometimes a deal breaker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Matrix within Matrix isn't possible... **yet**. Brandon has stated a few times that it's part of the long-term plan, and it's really more of the UI which is a stumbling block, rather than any major technical challenge.

> [... Matrix within Matrix is still something we intend to get working at some point.](https://plus.google.com/u/0/109046469195386381812/posts/YWHYCDJ2Fzw)
>
> [… Matrix within Matrix will be coming eventually. The UI is tough, but the code is all in place.](http://viget.com/extend/craft-cms-summit)

In the meantime, you may want to try using the [LJ Dynamic Fields plugin](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields/). It may not be *exactly* what you're dreaming of, but it can certainly help keep things a little DRY-er.

Comment: I think nexflo wants to duplicate the field setup, and reuse fields and entry types (matrix and others) in different sections, not the actual content.

Comment: IGNORE my comment. Misunderstood what this plugin actually does (thought it just populates existing fields with data like "Jack Daniels", "Jim Beam", etc.) :D

Comment: @carlcs Lol, no worries. I've used the LJ Dynamic Fields plugin a couple of times, and it really comes in handy in the right situations. For me, it was a big relief when creating multiple drop-down menus with the same (or similar) menu options.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2016, I have come across two options that attempt to handle the *matrix-within-a-matrix* scenario (to varying extents):

1. **Neo plugin**
   https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo
   Provides the ability to place *existing Craft fields* inside a matrix, group fields into tabs, and also nest blocks as "children" of other blocks.
2. **Super Table plugin**
   https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable
   Allows you to create repeatable fields that include almost any field type, including matrix.

This wiki page from the Neo repository also lists a few videos and other resources which delve into this topic:
https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo/wiki/6.-Resources

(I recently made the proud discovery that both these great plugins were made in my home city, Melbourne, Australia. Woo!)

Comment: I just started using Neo, and I'd recommend it very highly. Easily one of the best plugins for the Craft system.