# Loop for Similar Fields

Tags: templating

I'm in a situation where I have a handful of matrix blocks which have similar subfields. For example, I have a "Bios" block where there's an intro etc., but the a few repeating fields, imagine:

- Bio 1 Name (bioName1)
- Bio 1 Image (bioImage1)
- Bio 2 Name (bioName2)
- Bio 2 Image (bioImage2)
- etc. up to 6

In my template, I have some pretty redundent code when outputting these fields, like:

```
    {% if block.bioName1 %}
    <div class="bit">
        <div class="bio">
            {% for asset in block.bioImage1 %}
            <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="" />
            {% endfor %}
            <header>
                <h3>{{ block.bioName1 }}</h3>
                <p>{{ block.bioTitle1 }}</p>
            </header>
            {{ block.bioText1 }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if block.bioName2 %}
    <div class="bit">
        <div class="bio">
            {% for asset in block.bioImage2 %}
            <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="" />
            {% endfor %}
            <header>
                <h3>{{ block.bioName2 }}</h3>
                <p>{{ block.bioTitle2 }}</p>
            </header>
            {{ block.bioText2 }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

I'm wondering if it would be possible to somehow set this up as a loop with a counter to increment the vars (the field names always end with the count)? Any ideas? I tried a few things but have had no luck :/

Comment: Can you share screenshot your field set up? Would you be able to move the"bio" to its own block type so all the fields inside of a bio do not need to be numbered?

Comment: Hi Aaron - A stand alone block, or a "bios" channel [isn't a good fit for this project](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6732/solution-for-matrix-within-matrix-or-more-robust-table-fields). After trying those, we decided on this approach b.c it makes life a lot easier for the site's managers. It's working out fine, just trying to see if the templates can be a touch dry-er. If not, no biggie. Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "subscript" variable syntax to add the loop index to your field names automatically.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables

```
{% for i in 1..6 %}
  {% if block['bioName'~i] %}
    <div class="bit">
      <div class="bio">
        {% for asset in block['bioImage'~i] %}
          <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="" />
        {% endfor %}
        <header>
          <h3>{{ block['bioName'~i] }}</h3>
          <p>{{ block['bioTitle'~i] }}</p>
        </header>
        {{ block['bioText'~i] }}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I prefer this to the attribute function because it's a little simpler to look at. But the attribute function will work in some circumstances where dot notation and subscript syntax can't.

This is taken from the Twig docs link above:

> When the attribute contains special characters (like - that would be interpreted as the minus operator), use the attribute function instead to access the variable attribute:

```
{# equivalent to the non-working foo.data-foo #}
{{ attribute(foo, 'data-foo') }}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an excellent use case for twig's [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function.

> The `attribute` function can be used to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable:

```
{% for i in 1..6 %}
  {% if attribute(block, 'bioName'~i) %}
    <div class="bit">
      <div class="bio">
        {% for asset in attribute(block, 'bioImage'~i) %}
          <img src="{{asset.url}}"/>
          ...etc...
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Way better than my answer! Great idea to use attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires a little bit of set-up code, but it will keep all your HTML dry. Set up arrays with the values from your block fields. Loop through one of the arrays and use `loop.index0` to get the values you need in your HTML.

```
{% set names = [block.bioName1, block.bioName2, ...] %}
{% set titles = [block.bioTitle1, block.bioTitle2, ...] %}
{% set assets = [block.bioImage1, block.bioImage2, ...] %}
{% set texts = [block.bioText1, block.bioText2, ...] %}

{% for field in nameFields %}
    {% if field != '' %}
        <div class="bit">
            <div class="bio">
                {% for asset in assets[loop.index0] %}
                    <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="" />
                {% endfor %}
                <header>
                    <h3>{{ names[loop.index0] }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ titles[loop.index0] }}</p>
                </header>
                {{ block.texts[loop.index0] }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```